# Differences between pyserial 2.3 and 2.7?

Tags: pyserial

can someone list the differences between pyserial 2.6 and pyserial 2.7 
I'm unable to get the release notes for both the releases.

Comment: Is this resolved? If so please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

The list is maintained in [`CHANGES.rst` on GitHub](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#version-27------2013-10-17).

> ### Version 2.7      2013-10-17
>
> - Win32: setRTS and setDTR can be called before the port is opened and it will   set the initial state on port open.
> - Posix: add platform specific method: outWaiting (already present for Win32)
> - Posix: rename flowControl to setXON to match name on Win32, add   flowControlOut function
> - rfc2217: zero polls value (baudrate, data size, stop bits, parity) (Erik   Lundh)
> - Posix: [Patch pyserial:28] Accept any speed on Linux [update]
> - Posix: [Patch pyserial:29] PosixSerial.read() should "ignore" errno.EINTR
> - OSX: [Patch pyserial:27] Scan by VendorID/Product ID for USB Serial devices
> - Ensure working with bytes in write() calls
>
> Bugfixes:
>
> - [Bug 3540332] SerialException not returned
> - [Bug pyserial:145] Error in socket_connection.py
> - [Bug pyserial:135] reading from socket with timeout=None causes TypeError
> - [Bug pyserial:130] setup.py should not append py3k to package name
> - [Bug pyserial:117] no error on lost conn w/socket://
>
> Bugfixes (posix):
>
> - [Patch 3462364] Fix: NameError: global name 'base' is not defined
> - list_ports and device() for BSD updated (Anders Langworthy)
> - [Bug 3518380] python3.2 -m serial.tools.list_ports error
> - [Bug pyserial:137] Patch to add non-standard baudrates to Cygwin
> - [Bug pyserial:141] open: Pass errno from IOError to SerialException
> - [Bug pyserial:125] Undefined 'base' on list_ports_posix.py, function usb_lsusb
> - [Bug pyserial:151] Serial.write() without a timeout uses 100% CPU on POSIX
> - [Patch pyserial:30] [PATCH 1/1] serial.Serial() should not raise IOError.
>
> Bugfixes (win32):
>
> - [Bug 3444941] ctypes.WinError() unicode error
> - [Bug 3550043] on Windows in tools global name 'GetLastError' is not defined
> - [Bug pyserial:146] flush() does nothing in windows (despite docs)
> - [Bug pyserial:144] com0com ports ignored due to missing "friendly name"
> - [Bug pyserial:152] Cannot configure port, some setting was wrong. Can leave   port handle open but port not accessible